Native Linking Fails for Third-Party Dependencies in Custom React Native Package
I'm experimenting on a custom React Native package that includes both native (Kotlin for Android and Swift for iOS) and JavaScript code. This package encapsulates several APIs and functionalities and is designed to be used across multiple React Native apps.
The issue I'm facing is related to third-party package integration. Specifically, when I include a third-party dependency like @react-native-async-storage/async-storage in my custom package and then install my package into a React Native app, the native linking for the third-party package fails on the app side.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a custom React Native package with native and JS code.
Add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage as a dependency in custom package and expose any method like setItem or getItem.
Install custom package into a React Native app using npm or yarn.
Attempt to use the third-party dependency (AsyncStorage) functionality in the React Native app.

Expected Behavior:
The third-party package should work seamlessly in the React Native app after installing the custom package, with all native dependencies linked properly.
